# Trying to alphabetize in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Turn this string:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

into this string:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

This is all for Ruby. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: `str = "The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox"`; 
`str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

Comment: The sentence is a (famous) [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram). You are apparently supposed to sort the (down-cased) letters alphabetically.

Comment: ...and remove duplicates?

Comment: `s.downcase.chars.sort.uniq.map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?).join`

Comment: guess there's a few ways to do this. `.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq.sort.join`

Comment: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".replace("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`

Comment: one of the qualifiers for the question was that we couldn't use .replace

Comment: @steenslag, ha!, but the new string has no hand-holds, but technically I guess you're right.

Comment: You can employ `squeeze` at the end here instead of `uniq`ing the array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Relax bro. Explore ObjectSpace, it might  or might not be there. It's just Zen and the art of Object lifecycle maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
str.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq.sort.join #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

#### steps

```
str.scan(/[a-z]/) #returns all lowercase letters
str.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq #gets rid of duplicates
str.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq.sort #sorts in alphabetical order
str.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq.sort.join #makes a string
```

## Or another way:

```
str.scan(/[a-z]/).sort.join.squeeze #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

#### steps

```
str.scan(/[a-z]/) #returns all lowercase letters
str.scan(/[a-z]/).sort #sorts in alphabetical order
str.scan(/[a-z]/).sort.join #makes a string
str.scan(/[a-z]/).sort.join.squeeze #gets rid of duplicates
```

Comment: Note that this ignores the uppercase "T".

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Because faster is not always better

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".downcase.chars.uniq.sort.join.strip
```

Comment: I think you need to insert `uniq` and what about spaces?.

Comment: sorry , trying to beat the rush

Comment: Old Japanese saying: one who hesitates is less likely to make a fool of themself.

Comment: still wrong--the desired output doesn't include a space

Comment: That is true Cary and "Audacity augments courage; hesitation, fear."

Comment: Jacob the second (hesitated version) doesn't return spaces

Comment: Old Japanese saying: one who does not test is prone to making a fool of themself. Two suggestions: 1) move `uniq` before `sort` to reduce the burden on `sort`; and 2) use `each_char` (which returns an enumerator) rather than `chars` to avoid the creation of a temporary array (and remove the spaces!).

Comment: Using `each_char` avoids one temporary array, but `uniq` creates another one. Unfortunately, many "bang" methods are not chainable.

Comment: @Stefan bang methods can be chained if you embed them in a `tap` block.

Comment: @pjs that would chain the `tap` calls, not the bang methods ;-)

Comment: @Stefan yes, but it has the desired result of keeping chaining going.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
text.chars.sort.join
 => "        Tabcdeeefghhijklmnoooopqrrstuuvwxyz"
```

or to sort case insensitively:

```
str.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster solution matters, yet shows elegance :

```
str, hash = "This is cat", {}
str.each_char { |c| hash[c.downcase] = 1 }
('a'..'z').inject("") { |s, c| hash[c] ? s+c : s }
```